# Does using rage increase production speed of the Elixir Collector in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

I have been using the Elixir Collector and it has a Production Speed of 1 elixir per 8.5 seconds.

I also have an ability [rage](https://i.gyazo.com/5b44a92665ba2af0ac61b92e761df040.png) which "Increases troop movement and attack speed. **Buildings attack faster and summon troops quicker**, too." It has a 35% boost to these attributes.

Emphasis mine.

I have been using rage on my [Elixir Collectors like so](https://i.gyazo.com/80e4f3fb64a0ce8d5178a0aaad96d83d.png), and am curious if this is doing anything. I tried timing it so see if it was working, but due to me playing the game/the timing of the placement I was unable to get an accurate reading.

Overall I am wondering, will the rage sped up my Elixir Collector by 35% for the duration the rage is affecting the building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. After a not-very-recent update, Elixir Collectors are affected by all the speed-modifying effects. These include Rage, Freeze, Zap, Ice Spirit's freeze effect, Ice Wizard and Ice Golem.

Comment: I think that Rage had this effect already before that update, but the other spells didn't. So I thought it was good to mention it (for a little extra post length).